Question about running k means cluster analysis
In a previous analysis I had 3 groups of subjects - group x with 35 subjects, control group y with 25 subjects, and control group z with 25 subjects. For each group I have levels of 6 different biomarkers (we can call them biomarkers a, b, c, d, e, and f). I compared the level of each biomarker between groups and found no significant differences. However, I have reason to believe that there will be meaningful subgroups of subjects in group x that will differ in level of one or more of the metabolites from one or both of the control groups. For all 85 of the participants I have other data that I think might be relevant to building the subgroups - particularly, I have data on 7 different types of IQ (let's call them IQ a, b, c, d, e, f, and g), and two demographic variables, specifically age and years of education. Now what I wanted to do is run k means cluster analysis on group x to find any meaningful subgroups in this group that involved the biomarkers - for example I might find two clusters; one with high levels of biomarker d, low IQ b, and low years of education (let's call this cluster A) and another with low levels of biomarker e, high IQ f, and high age (let's call this cluster B). Then the idea would be to take each cluster and compare the levels of biomarker involved in the cluster to the levels of those biomarkers in the two control groups. For example, for cluster A I would compare the level of biomarker d in group x to the level of biomarker d in each of the two control groups, and if I found that group x differed in level of biomarker d from either or both of the control groups I could say that there's a subgroup of subjects in group x with high levels of biomarker d, low IQ b, and low years of education that differs in level of biomarker d from one or both of the control groups. Then for cluster B I would compare the level of biomarker e to to the level of biomarker e in each of the two control groups, and if I found that group x differed in level of biomarker e from either or both of the control groups I could say that there's a subgroup of subjects in group x with low levels of biomarker e, high IQ f, and high age  that differs in level of biomarker e from one or both of the control groups.
The above cluster analysis seemed like a good path to take. However, I'm a total newb to cluster analysis. And I was told that the 35 subjects in group x isn't enough subjects to run k means cluster analysis on because if I were to run it on such a small group any results I would get would most likely just be noise. So I would need more subjects to get away with doing the cluster analysis. Unfortunately I don't have any more subjects for group x. So here's what I thought of to do, and I want to see if it's a valid and effective way of answering my research question. To get more data I will include in the cluster analysis not only the subjects from group x, but also the subjects from controls groups y and z. That will give me 85 subjects total for the cluster analysis, which I imagine will be enough. Then hypothetically, let's say that I find the same two clusters mentioned above but including participants from all three groups (who knows whether that will actually be the case, but let's say just as a hypothetical example) - Let's say for cluster A again we have high levels of biomarker d, low IQ b, and low years of education and let's say cluster A has 12 subjects from group x, 2 from group y, and one from group z; and then for cluster B again we have low levels of biomarker e, high IQ f, and high age, and cluster B has 11 subjects from group x, 3 from group z, and 1 from group y. Then here's what I'm thinking of doing: for cluster A I can take the 12 subjects from group x (n=12) and compare their level of biomarker d to the level of biomarker d to the level of biomarker d in control group y (n=25) and then to the level of biomarker d in control group z (n=25). Similarly, for cluster B I would take the 11 subjects from group x (n=11) and compare their level of biomarker e to the level of biomarker e in control group y (n=25) and then to the level of biomarker d in control group z (n=25). So my question is whether this will be a valid and effective way of still being able to run the cluster analysis to answer my research question of whether there are meaningful subgroups in group x that differ in the level of one or more of the biomarkers from one or both of the control groups.
Thanks for any help!

This looks like a question for which you better get together with a statistician for a proper collaboration. Generally (even with larger samples) if you run k-means and you fix the number of clusters, you cannot know whether the number of clusters is appropriate and whether you are just splitting up homogeneous data into meaningless subgroups. If you put different groups together you may need more clusters, but the more clusters you fit, the more data you need (also it depends on the dimensions; n=35 with 2 variables and 2 clusters is fine but with 6 vars or even more it is problematic).

Also doing clustering and then using the same data for another analysis based on the clusters like comparing individual biomarkers will bias the latter analysis, if I understand correctly what you have in mind.

There are methods for estimating the number of clusters and for testing homogeneity, but all this requires care and checking against the data (k-means is not the best clustering method for all kinds of data)  and your overall description is too complicated so that it isn't really clear where to go from there.

@ChristianHennig Thanks for your thoughtful reply. I will likely be working with a statistician in the near future, but I'm trying to get as much done on my own as possible first. With respect to determining # of clusters, I'm planning on using the elbow method or maybe silhouette method - isn't that a way of determining appropriate # of clusters? As per your concern about not being able to know whether you're just splitting up homogeneous data into meaningless subgroups - I have good reason to believe based on past literature that there will be meaningful subgroups within group x.

@ChristianHennig continued from last comment... Moreover, as per your concern about not being able to know whether you're just splitting up homogeneous data into meaningless subgroups; can't I just use Levene's test or some other equivalent test to test for homogeneity of variance?

@ChristianHennig Can you elaborate on how running analysis to compare individual biomarkers post clustering will bias the analysis? From what I've read it's common to find clusters and then compare those clusters to each other or other groups - e.g., in SPSS you can have SPSS create a separate variable assigning a cluster number to each of your participants and then you can use that to compare certain clusters after the fact. I've been told that this is a relatively common thing to do. Why would this bias things exactly?

@ChristianHennig As per your concern about whether k means is best for my data, are you talking about checking whether my data meet the assumptions for k means cluster analysis? I looked at all the assumptions of k means vs two step cluster analysis vs hierarchical cluster analysis and k means seemed to be the best fit for my data.

Sorry, there'd be too much to say and too much to ask, and I can't really be sure about anything without seeing the data. Don't have the time to do full advisory on CV for free. Levene's test will be invalid if data have been clustered before and groups were formed based on the same data used in the test.
